# Strange Lag in Serial ReadLine

Tags: c#, serialization, lag

I've been playing around with a sensor as part of an older project passed on to me and I've started reading in the serial output as a string and printing it to the console along with a timer that records elapsed time while printing it. Most of the data logs smoothly, but there are consistent line where the time elapsed is greatly increased. I am using a RazorIMU with some custom code in it to output the individual accelerometer, magnetometer, and gyroscope readings as a string, and the issue may be arising from that, though it is a bit much to post on here so I'll just put my C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace SensorTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort com = new SerialPort("COM7", 57600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            com.Open();

            Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
            float deltaT = 0.0f;

            com.ReadLine();
            clock.Start();
            while (true)
            {

                deltaT = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                clock.Restart();
                Console.Write(deltaT + "ms:");
                Console.WriteLine(com.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a small snippet of the console output with the lag spike.

```
1ms:-4.87,4.64,-234.27,6.00,3.00,9.00,1.17,50.83,-75.50
4ms:-3.89,4.64,-232.38,5.00,2.00,8.00,0.83,51.17,-75.17
1ms:-3.89,4.64,-232.38,6.00,2.00,9.00,1.17,50.50,-75.17
1ms:-4.87,4.64,-231.44,6.00,2.00,9.00,0.83,51.33,-75.67
4ms:-4.87,4.64,-231.44,7.00,2.00,9.00,1.17,51.17,-75.00
1ms:-2.92,3.71,-231.44,7.00,2.00,8.00,1.00,51.00,-75.33
69ms:-2.92,3.71,-231.44,6.00,2.00,8.00,1.17,50.67,-75.17
0ms:-3.89,4.64,-232.38,7.00,1.00,8.00,1.00,51.00,-75.50
4ms:-4.87,4.64,-232.38,6.00,1.00,8.00,1.17,51.00,-75.00
1ms:-4.87,4.64,-232.38,8.00,2.00,8.00,1.17,50.67,-75.00
```

As I said before, it could be the IMU, but if it is the code causing the issue, any advice or even a "you're an idiot, do this instead" would be greatly appreciated.

Small Update: Adding in a pause shows that it seems like the data read in is annexed and output in the order it is received. If I keep the sensor in one position at a high pause, it takes a good amount of time before the console displays the change. Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: How could it possibly not be the IMU? Your code shows 10 lines produced in 86ms. Do you think the IMU might have produced 11 and you missed one somehow?

Comment: Well, I was mostly functioning under the assumption that everything coded before I got my hands on it was "working" and since I'm still fairly new to C# and coding in general I assumed the error fell on my end.

Comment: Without knowing when the sending device actually sent the data, it's impossible to determine where the problem might be. It's almost certainly not in your code, but it could be in the `SerialPort` class (unlikely), in the low-level serial port controller, or in the sending device. Or, who knows ... maybe your computer burps periodically.

Comment: Belches are very possible. I'll look through the differences between the vanilla IMU code and the code I received with the project and check for differences.

Comment: Actually, something's buffering. Your lines are 50 bytes long. At 57,600 bps, that's about 5760 *bytes* per second. So receiving 50 bytes should take about 8 milliseconds. I suspect that the individual line times of 0 to 4 ms are just the times required to get data from the buffer. The 69 ms is probably spent waiting to receive more data (multiple lines) from the device.

Comment: Do you suspect the time gap is from the IMU code or do you think it is from the hardware and cannot be improved?

Comment: It's possible it's the IMU code. It'd be worth looking at. You might also increase the serial port's [ReadBufferSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx) to, say, 65536 (the default is 4096), just to see if that changes the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for analyzing what exactly is happening is [this serial port sniffer](http://freeserialanalyzer.com/).
With it you can see any byte that goes on Tx/Rx even if that byte won't read by your code - then you could see if the blame is on the IMU.